# disable hostname in tmux "list windows" output

Tags: tmux

When I list windows in `tmux` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> by default) + <kbd>w</kbd>, then I see following list:

```
(0)  0: martin@martin- "martin"
(1)  1: SSH to 82.196.6.62(root@debian-512mb-ams2-01)  "martin"
```

How to configure `tmux` in a way that my hostname `"martint"` is not displayed? In other words desired output would be:

```
(0)  0: martin@martin-
(1)  1: SSH to 82.196.6.62(root@debian-512mb-ams2-01)
```

Answer (score 2):

The part in double-quotes is the value of `#{pane_title}`. You can override the format used by the command by setting up your own binding in your `~/.tmux.conf` file omitting that variable:

```
bind-key w choose-window -F "#{window_index}: #{window_name}#{window_flags}"
```

Comment: Cheers @meuh, any idea on [how to customize the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72937438/tmux-how-to-filter-the-current-session-windows-using-choose-tree-and-format-the)